# How to pull index of a set of values from a column?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataset called Groceries.  Stock has the bar codes of food items in a store and the type of stock they are.  I load it into pandas as a dataframe and I want to create lists of barcodes of all the items of a particular stock type so that I can then use the barcode to identify information from other dataframes.

What is the most efficient method for doing so using pandas?

```
Groceries = {'Stock_type': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Chicken', 'Orange', 'Chocolate'], 'Bar_Code': [12442, 23534, 53245, 15453, 23453, 13451]}

Groceries_df = pd.DataFrame(data=Groceries)

Groceries_df
   Bar_Code  Stock_type
0     12442       Apple
1     23534       Apple
2     53245      Orange
3     15453     Chicken
4     23453      Orange
5     13451   Chocolate
```

In essence this is the same problem I am experiencing with another larger data set I want to run a analysis on.  I need to collect a list of unique identifying meta-data from one data frame so I can pull values for those data-points from other dataframes.

Comment: Hello, can you show us precisely what you want to obtain in the end? I'm not sure I get it.

Comment: ggrelet I've rewritten the question.  Does this make it more clear?

Comment: @AngusCampbell This should give you the list of barcode for a specific stock type Groceries_df[Groceries_df['Stock_type']=='Apple']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load data to a data frame

```
import pandas as pd
Groceries = {'Stock_type': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Chicken', 'Orange', 'Chocolate'], 'Bar_Code': [12442, 23534, 53245, 15453, 23453, 13451]}
Groceries_df = pd.DataFrame(Groceries)
```

Barcode of all items of specific stock type (say Apple)

```
Groceries_df[Groceries_df['Stock_type']=='Apple']
```

Python list of Barcode (converts series of BarCode to list)

```
list(Groceries_df[Groceries_df['Stock_type']=='Apple']['Bar_Code'])
```